# Labeling/categorization of image corner options

Tags: image, labeling, categorization

In a CMS backend-context under image corner options, how to label/categorize the options?

Suggestions for formats (imagine the bullet points are radio button-like options) including a few presets:

SUGGESTION 1:

**Rounded corners**

- No curve
- Small curve
- Big curve
- More options...

SUGGESTION 2:

**Corners**

- Square
- Small curve
- Big curve
- More options...

I'm not a native English speaker, so I'm not sure whether "curve" is the correct term. But that's really not the point. 
My uncertainty is more along the lines of: What is better in terms of the headlines and the first option-combos:

- "Rounded Corners" + "No curve"

OR

- "Corners" + "Square"?

Perhaps "Square" should be "Perpendicular"? 
In reality, the first option in both suggestions is "don't alter the corners" (they might have been edited a priori in dedicated editing software and thus not necessarily square/perpendicular).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More than the label, the most explicit for users are **small thumbnails**. For example, in Photoshop Express:

[image]

Additionally, you could have a slider below for fine-tuning the strength of the curve (and the thickness of the border, if you provide such an option).

Comment: Yes, I agree. Actually, what I didn't make explicit in my question is that the disjunct options are not implemented using text-labeled radio buttons, but by thumbnail-"adorned" buttons illustrating the setting as you suggest. And actually the "More options..." button gives access to a slider where the curve can be fine-tuned.

Comment: I'm still in doubt, though, whether to label the "array of settings" "Corners" or "Rounded corners". The former is more of an inherent property of the image whereas the latter is more of an add-on property.

Comment: I would pick "Rounded corners" personally because just "Corners" may include rectangle-type corners as well, so the first one is more explicit imho.